Angular 18 with keen-slider nativeElement error
I use keen-slider with angular, in the standard way. In html:
<div class="keen-slider mt-0 w-full" #sliderReco  >

and in the component
@ViewChild("sliderReco") sliderReco!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
sliderR!: KeenSliderInstance;

ngAfterViewInit() {
setTimeout(() => {
    this.sliderR = new KeenSlider(this.sliderReco.nativeElement, {
    loop: false,
    slides: {
      perView: () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 768)
          return 1;
        else
          return 3;
      },
      spacing:20,
    },
    renderMode: "performance",
    drag: false,
  })
});

But when executing I have the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
I can't found the problem.  I use this in early projets, without problems.
I tought that window.innerWidth may not be available (even if the slider is the afterViewInit cycle,
and I tried to add both in the afterViewInit and onInit.
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
but it doesn't work.
Help please.

please share more of the HTML code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue happening

Sorry to not have access to stackblitz, but the html is :

@for (cli of clients(); track cli.id) {

}

@mtabaj Please edit your question with the new information.

I solve the problem, that was that window elements were not charged immediately.  I added 2000ms to setTimeout, end everything is ok.
